# How to get rows between 2 dates

Tags: php, mysql

In my MySQL database, I have a `startdate` and an `enddate` field. Using today's date from PHP, is there a way to only select rows where the `startdate` is before today's date and the `enddate` is after today's date?

Comment: Have you tried searching the interwebs before posting here?

Comment: `WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date`

Comment: if you are storing dates in fields with `datetime` type - you can read sql manual and use `between`. if not... get a book about databases

Comment: Would rather post here and get the answer in 30 seconds than read through a book for a quick question.

Comment: What datatypes are the dates in? It doesn't necessarily change the resulting SQL, but people store dates in a few different ways (I've known a few places that store unix timestamps for dates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
WHERE startdate >= todays_date AND enddate <= todaysdate
```

or

```
WHERE todays_date BETWEEN startdate and enddate
```

[Docs for BETWEEN here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Rather than use PHP to get the current date use the build in MySQL function [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) so :

```
WHERE startdate >= CURDATE() AND enddate <= CURDATE()
```

or

```
WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN startdate and enddate
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `BETWEEN`:

```
WHERE today between START_DATE AND END_DATE
```

Comment: Is there a way to get today (todays date) from mysql rather than php?

Comment: I'm sure there's a system call that will get it for you: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize SQL's between clause:

```
$query = "SELECT colList FROM table WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN startdate AND enddate";
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not provided any code so i am assuming you start and end date in db have `datetime` datatypes,

`$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` will produce somethig like `2012-06-14 14:46:00` and this is format Mysql understands, so can use it in ur query

`select * from 'your-table' where $today BETWEEN 'start_date' AND 'END_DATE'`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My PHP and SQL are rusty, but the following should work where $date is the variable where you have put today's date.

```
$results = mysqli_query( $conn, 
    "select * from yourTable where startdate<'{$date}' AND enddate>'{$date}'" );
```